# SQLite WHERE clause with date gt and gte issue idential results

Tags: django-models, sqlite

I use SQLite as temporary db backend to debug my django application. I need to select records that have datetime gt (greater than) given value, but looks like SQLite ignores gt and always use gte (greater than or equal)!

For example:

```
model.objects.all().filter(Q(field_foo__exact='foo'), Q(field_date__gt='2014-11-03'))[:3]
```

which works just fine except for one case, namely, if table already has a record with field_date that equals to the search criteria. So, __gt acts as __gte

Also, I logged the query generated by django ORM and played with this query. Same results. Query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (foo='foo' AND date>date('2014-11-03'))
```

issues identical results to query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (foo='foo' AND date>=date('2014-11-03'))
```

if there is a record with date exactly '2014-11-03'.

Is this known feature? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the exact value of the string in the record?

Comment: @CL., triggered by your question I looked carefully at the values and found little bug - request url wasn't encoded. thus, timezone sign '+' was interpreted as space, which confused timestamp parser, giving always incorrect datetime object, which was used to query the database. encoding the url solved the problem! thanks!